# Como criar botão com função para exportar o DataTable para (.csv) em jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables, datatable

Tenho o seguinte botão:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "tableTools": {
      "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnExportar">Exportar</button>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>E-Mail</th>
      <th>Profissão</th>


    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Nome
      </th>
      <th>
        E-Mail
      </th>
      <th>
        Profissão
      </th>



    </tr>
  </tfoot>

  <tbody>
    <td>Tiago Ferezin</td>
    <td>mail@email.com</td>
    <td>Programador</td>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Como vemos no código a função não está funcionando, não sei o motivo, e gostaria de associar essa função ao botão exportar para que quando o usuário clicar nesse botão, já abre a janela de download para baixar em *.csv, o contéudo do DataTable, no PC do usuário.

Como se resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Datatables tem um implementação de [**File Export**](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html) que faz o que você precisa e tem um tópico especifico para [**csv**](https://datatables.net/reference/button/csv). Para que tudo funcione você tem que fazer os importes de todos os arquivos listados logo abaixo do exemplo no site. Segue um [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/p8co5r3e) para que você teste :)

Comment: No jsfiddle deu certo, porém depois de fazer todas as importações e tudo e colocar de acordo com o que esta no jsfiddle postado, tambem nao resolveu

Comment: @TiagoFerezin , opa .. qual a versão da DataTables que você está utilizando ? e é muito importante verificar a sequencia de importação dos javascript :)

Comment: @TiagoFerezin se quiser baixar com as referencias importadas, disponibilizei para você [**aqui**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0V7Xw4A59O1VDRNZmNkenk3UnM5VFZDdVlJdHdSdFI0cUZN/view) espero que ajude :)

Comment: rodou mas ele gerou um botao, eu queria colocar essa função dentro do meu botão que personalizei já, tem como.? Caso não, teria outra forma de se fazer isso? nem que seja pelo lado do Servidor com o Java mesmo.

Comment: E pior alem de geram o botao, desconfigurou tudo meu DataTables, e agora?

Comment: @TiagoFerezin, só é possível utilizar os botões gerados pela biblioteca, pois os botões de "Copy", "CSV", "Excel" e "PDF" foram implementados utilizando Adobe Flash. o problema de desconfiguração deve ser algum conflito com os arquivos css,  basta ir removendo os novos e adicionando os antigos :)